# View jenkins workspace on slave

Tags: jenkins

We're running tests and producing build files on a jenkins master and a jenkins slave for extra parallellisation, our RCPTT tests takes ages.

Our problem is that Jenkins ->  -> Show workspace only shows the workspace on the master, so we have no way to get the builds except copying files manually over ssh.

We don't want duplication since different patches run either on master or slave, and we want to be able to get the files from both master and slave nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Copy To Slave Plugin" to copy any files from master to slave.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Jenkins pipeline plugin https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

then you can use stash / unstash:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build

Her an example: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins